# How to conditionally render a class based on array index?

Tags: angular

I have a negativeArray of length 5 and I want to apply the 'rating-type__pipe--active' class only to the first three elements in the code below and not on the last two elements. Is there any way that I can achieve this. I tried flipping it based on the index in the flip function below but it doesn't work. A hint here would suffice!

```
<div class="rating-type__bar-wrapper rating-type__bar-left">
                  <ng-container *ngFor="let opt of negativeArray; index as i">
                    <div class="rating-type__pipe"  [class.rating-type__pipe--active]="isNegativeActive" (click)="isNegativeActive=!isNegativeActive">
                        <div class="rating-type__pipe-pillar">
                            <span [ngStyle]="{'height': (100 - (i * 20))+'%', 'opacity': (1 - (i * 0.2))}" class="rating-type__pipe-pillar-bg"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="rating-type__pipe-text">{{opt.text}}</div>
                    </div>
                  </ng-container>
              </div>
```

```
isNegativeActive: boolean = false;

flip(index) {
    
    if(index > 2) {
    this.isNegativeActive=this.isNegativeActive;
  } 
  else {
    this.isNegativeActive=!this.isNegativeActive
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you call your flip function, but if you want to add a class based on an index you can do the following:

```
<div class="rating-type__bar-wrapper rating-type__bar-left">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let opt of negativeArray; let i as index">
    <div class="rating-type__pipe"  [class.rating-type__pipe--active]="i < 3" (click)="isNegativeActive=!isNegativeActive">
        <div class="rating-type__pipe-pillar">
            <span [ngStyle]="{'height': (100 - (i * 20))+'%', 'opacity': (1 - (i * 0.2))}" class="rating-type__pipe-pillar-bg"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="rating-type__pipe-text">{{opt.text}}</div>
    </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

writing `[class.rating-type__pipe--active]="i < 3"` makes sure the class will be applied to only index 0, 1 and 2 - when the expression is evaluated to `true`. It's also worth noting that `isNegativeActive` is single for all elements in the array (because its a property of the component) so changing it will affect all elements